# Vite.js Dynamic Image Loading Fails In Production

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a problem in importing dynamic assets in production mode. When I ran the development environment everything works fine and the assets loads...but when I build the `Vue.js` application, assets won't load and I gets below error:
`TypeError: URL constructor: ../../../assets/images/name.png is not a valid URL.`
how can I fix this issue?

#### Vue Example

```html
<img :src="findImageFromNumber(card.cartNumber)" alt="image" width="25" />
```

```js
function findImageFromNumber(number: string) {
  const name = identify(number).english;
  const path = new URL('../../../assets/images/banks/' + name + '.png', import.meta.url);
  return path.href
}
```

#### Vite.js Config

```json
export default defineConfig({
  root: './',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '/@/': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    },
  },
  publicDir: 'assets',
  mode: 'production',
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    sourcemap: true,
    target: ['es2019', 'safari11', 'firefox60', 'chrome61', 'node12'],
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 500,
    minify: false,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    assetsInlineLimit: 2048,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`,
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes('vue')) {
            return 'react';
          } else if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
            return 'vendor';
          }
        },
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    legacy({
      polyfills: ['es.promise.finally', 'es/map', 'es/set'],
      modernPolyfills: ['es.promise.finally']
    })
  ],
})
```

**Note: Everything works fine in development and it only fails in production...**

Comment: Vite Documentation said: During the production build, Vite will perform necessary transforms so that the URLs still point to the correct location even after bundling and asset hashing. But it seems like it won't

Comment: It seems the usage of `new URL` is incorrect. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Answer (score 0):

Assets is your public dir. Should it just be `/assets/images/banks`, according to the docs?

Comment: Same error happened again